# how to set hbase event-time when make a temporal table join in flink sql

Tags: join, apache-flink, temporal

left is a fact table from kafka

```
CREATE TABLE  dig_user_join_kafka (
id string,
username string,
city_id string,
create_time TIMESTAMP(3),
WATERMARK FOR create_time AS create_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
```

)

right is a dimension  table from hbase

```
CREATE TABLE dim_city_hbase (
 id string,
 info ROW＜
name string
＞,
 PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
)
```

I want to make a temporal table join with event-time

```
insert into dim_city_join_hbase 
select id as id, 
ROW(username, city, create_time) as info 
from ( 
select kj.id as id, 
kj.username as username, 
hj.info.name as city, 
kj.create_time as create_time 
from dig_user_join2_kafka kj
left join dim_city_hbase FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF kj.create_time  hj
 on kj.city_id = hj.id
)
```

now, error is

```
The main method caused an error: Event-Time Temporal Table Join requires both primary
key and row time attribute in versioned table, but no row time attribute can be found
```

it mean's hbase table has no row time ,how to set hbase event-time?

many examples show hbase temporal table join with proctime, but no one use event-time,

Answer (score 0):

use the system function "PROCTIME()" or "CURRENT_ROW_TIMESTAMP()" to add a field as rowtime then set the watermark :

```
" update_time AS CURRENT_ROW_TIMESTAMP(), " +
" WATERMARK FOR update_time AS update_time, " +
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add event-time attribute on the hbase dim table.
From your code table dig_user_join_kafka had set event-time attribute,dimension table can do like:

```
CREATE TABLE dim_city_hbase (
  id STRING,
  info ROW<name STRING, ts STRING>,  // ts is self defined column
  rowtime AS TO_TIMESTAMP(ts),
  WATERMARK FOR rowtime AS rowtime,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
)
```

Or, like @haoqi answer

```
CREATE TABLE dim_city_hbase (
  id STRING,
  info ROW<name STRING>,  
  update_time AS CURRENT_ROW_TIMESTAMP(),
  WATERMARK FOR update_time AS update_time,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
)
```

reference:[official description of rowtime-attributes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/overview/#rowtime-attributes)